# Why are Ken Jennings and Mayim Bialik introduced differently?

Tags: jeopardy

Ken Jennings and Mayim Bialik have been sharing the hosting duties on Jeopardy this season. But Johnny Gilbert announces them differently during the introduction. Mayim is "the host of Jeopardy" while Ken is "hosting Jeopardy".

I know Ken is also a producer of the show, but why would that mean he should be introduced differently?

Comment: Probably a credit difference in their contracts which can also be related to pay.

Comment: I have no evidence, but a popular theory I've read on Jeopardy's Reddit page is that Ken asked not to be referred to as "the host" of Jeopardy, in respect to Alex Trebek, the true "host" of Jeopardy.

Comment: I suspect it’s because Mayim Bialik is a permanent host, while Ken is still technically just doing the job on an interim basis.